# Изменять переменную одновременно в нескольких компонентах Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js

Есть родительский компонент, в нем есть переменная которая отвечает за состояние чекбокса. Чекбокс это дочерний компонент и нужно чтобы в случае изменения переменной в род. компоненте эта переменная менялась также в дочернем компоненте

Род. компонент

```
<template>
  <div class="new-products">
      <div>
        <CheckBoxInput
          @checked="checkedPrice"
          id="product-price"
          :model="modal.purchaseAgreement.price"
        />
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CheckBoxInput from "@/components/inputs/CheckBoxInput";

export default {
  components: {
    CheckBoxInput,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      modal: {
        purchaseAgreement: {
          price: false,
        },
      },
    };
  },

  methods: {
    checkedPrice(model) {
      this.modal.purchaseAgreement.price = model;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Дочерний компонент

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      :id="id.replace(' ', '')"
      v-model="model"
      type="checkbox"
      @input="v && v.$touch()"
      @click="checkedInput"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CheckBox",
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      default: "id" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000),
    },
    model: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      active: this.model,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    checkedInput() {
      this.active = !this.active;
      this.$emit("checked", this.active);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Мой вариант работает, но с багом, из-за чего при очистке переменной в главном компоненте, дочерний не меняется с первого раза

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как описано в документации - [Настройка v-model у компонента](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-v-model-%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0), создаете компонент `CheckBoxInput`, как:

```
const CheckBoxInput = Vue.component('check-box-input', {
  model: {
    prop: 'checked',
    event: 'change'
  },
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      default: "id" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000),
    },
    checked: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  template: `
  <div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Checkbox [ID:{{id}}]</legend>
    <input
      :id="id.replace(' ', '')"
      :checked="checked"
      @change="$emit('change', $event.target.checked)"
      type="checkbox"
    />
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  `,
})
```

После этого подключаете этот компонент в ваше приложение, как:

```
<check-box-input id="product-price" v-model="modal.purchaseAgreement.price"></check-box-input>
```

```js
const CheckBoxInput = Vue.component('check-box-input', {
  model: {
    prop: 'checked',
    event: 'change'
  },
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      default: "id" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000),
    },
    checked: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  template: `
  <div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Checkbox [ID:{{id}}]</legend>
    <input
      :id="id.replace(' ', '')"
      :checked="checked"
      @change="$emit('change', $event.target.checked);$emit('checked', $event.target.checked)"
      type="checkbox"
    />
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  `,
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    CheckBoxInput,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      modal: {
        purchaseAgreement: {
          price: false,
        },
      },
    };
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="new-products">
    <div>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Родительский компонент</legend>
        <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
        <button @click="modal.purchaseAgreement.price = !modal.purchaseAgreement.price">Изменить checkbox из родителя - {{modal.purchaseAgreement.price}}</button>
        <check-box-input id="product-price" v-model="modal.purchaseAgreement.price"></check-box-input>
        <check-box-input id="product-price2" v-model="modal.purchaseAgreement.price"></check-box-input>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

В итоге вы получаете возможность управления состоянием чекбокса и соответственно получаете возможность изменения его состояния как из родительского компонента(модифицируя значение свойства, которое используется в качестве `v-model`) так и из его самого(полагаясь на функционал компонента)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло